# Why can I encrypt a web.config but not decrypt it on the same box? Error is The parameter is incorrect

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm getting an error where I'm able to encrypt a web.config file but not decrypt it. For example, I have my clear text connection strings inside web.config and I encrypt it with this command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Encrypting configuration section...
Succeeded!
```

When I immediately try to decrypt it, I get this error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Decrypting configuration section...
Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The parameter is incorrect.
 (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\IdentityManager\web.config line 9)

The parameter is incorrect.

Failed!
```

I tried deleting and recreating the RSA keys, but this did not work either:

```
aspnet_regiis -pz "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey"

aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey"
```

I'm not sure why I can encrypt successfully and not decrypt. To me, RSA is symmetric.

I am a local administrator on the box.

Comment: couple ideas, but don't know why it would work one way and not the other: put directory in quotes; open cmd as admin.

Comment: Are you encrypting and decrypting on the same machine? Have you changed the private or public key?

Comment: @wazz - I am running as admin

As an additional note, this machine was upgraded in place from 2012 R2 to 2019.

Comment: @samwu - It is being done on the same machine. I did not change the keys initially. To troubleshoot, I recreated the key as state and re-encrypted the file. It still fails to decrypt.

Comment: Can you post your web.config file? how did you set the 
 RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue when .NET is configured to use OEAP.  I was able to find this article that showed a similar problem:

[aspnet_regiis web.config encryption [Error message from the provider: Bad Data.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533198/aspnet-regiis-web-config-encryption-error-message-from-the-provider-bad-data)

I updated the machine.config file, rebooted, and the problem went away.